# single.php being ignored, going straight to attachment.php

Tags: permalinks, templates

All of a sudden, for no reason I can tell, my single.php template is being ignored and falling back to using attachment.php

If I switch permalinks to use the ?p=123 style, then it works perfectly. As soon as I switch back to using the Post Name style - which has been working with no problem at all up until now - the page starts using the attachment.php template instead of single.php

I have tried re-saving permalinks and I have tried completely deleting my .htaccess file and then re-creating it manually. That didn't work. I then tried deleting it again and letting WP automatically create it by resaving permalinks again. That didn't work either. I haven't installed any plugins between it working and not working. Basically, I'm at a bit of a loss. Any help very gratefully received.

EDIT:

By the way, this is the contents of my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

EDIT 2: I should've mentioned that permalinks work just fine on all my static Page templates. Its only single.php that isn't working.

Comment: What's the post type of the post you're looking at? Have you disabled all plugins and reverted to the default theme to track down where the issue is?

Comment: Thanks Tom, just tried both - still not working. The post type is just an ordinary post.

Comment: It is that happening only with some posts or all of them?

Comment: All of them. It seems like the template hierarchy is just skipping single.php completely.

Comment: It seems that there is something broken in your site; unfortunately we can not (at least me) say what happen with the information you have provided. To solve the issue, a deep look in your site may be needed. Are you sure you have tried with all plugins deactivated and with a default theme?

Comment: Yep, just tried it again. All plugins deactivated and I've tried 2012, 2013 and 2014 themes. On pages where it should be using single.php, a look at the body tag classes in the posts source code show that the template being used is attachment.php

Comment: Keep in mind we're assuming that you're using the latest WordPress, with no modifications to WP Core, no mu-plugins, no custom themes/plugins activated, and a standard Apache setup, and this still happens

Answer (score 0):

OK, well, I've put the search for a proper answer on hold and instead cobbled together a 'for now' solution. First, in the referring page that is linking to the individual Post page, I've added this:

```
$theid = $post->ID;
echo "<li><a href='";
the_permalink();
echo "?id=" . $theid;
echo "'>";
echo "blah";
echo "</a>";
```

So, on line 1 of above code, I get the ID of the Post I'm linking to and on line 4, I'm adding that id to a query string so the link is then:

```
http://somedomain.co.uk/post-name/?id=whatever_the_id_is
```

And then in attachment.php I have:

1) For standard WP fields (the_content etc) the ID seems to get passed automatically and pulls out the right data.

2) For custom fields (I'm using Advanced Custom Fields plugin), the ID is **not** being passed automatically, so I have:

```
//pseudo code assuming cleaning and testing var exists etc
$pid = $_GET['id'];
$url = get_field('custom_field_here', $pid);
```

This then pulls the custom fields for the right Post.

I'm aware this is not a great solution but it'll have to suffice until I can figure out why single.php is being ignored.